# Call a class function from a async class function

Tags: javascript, class, asynchronous

I want to call a function inside a class from another function inside the same class. This works well with `this.myFunction()`. But when the calling function is for example triggered by a click eventhandler, `this` for the class is no longer available.

Normally I would use `new MyClass().myFunction()`but in this case I am losing values and objects from "the first" instance.

In my case I started an interval, that i want to clear after a button click. But when I create a new instance of my class, the interval is of course not longer available.

How should I call `functionToCall()` from the `myButton.addEventListener("click", function () {`? Or is this a generally wrong approach?

**MyClass.js**

```js
export class MyClass {

constructor() {
 this.refreshIntervalId = 0;
}

functionToCall() {

 clearInterval(this.refreshIntervalId); // this has to be the instance

}

buttonFunction() {

 let myButton = document.getElementById(myButton);

 myButton.addEventListener("click", function () {
  this.functionToCall(); // doesn't work (of course)
 });

}

startInterval() {
 this.refreshIntervalId = setInterval(() => {
   this.buttonFunction()
 }, 1000);
}

}
```

**index.js**

```js
import {
  MyClass
} from './MyClass';

let myClass = new MyClass();
myClass.startInterval();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you replace

```
myButton.addEventListener("click", function () {
   this.functionToCall(); // doesn't work (of course)
});
```

with

```
myButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
   this.functionToCall();
});
```

then within the handler, `this` will be bound to the `this` that exists in the scope in which the arrow function was declared. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions for more info.

Alternatively, you can explicitly bind the `this` value within the function to the "external" `this` using the [`Function.bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind) method:

```
myButton.addEventListener("click", (function () {
   this.functionToCall();
}).bind(this));
```

Answer (score 0):

This works very well!

In my case i still needed the clicked button as object too.
Binding `this` means, that you loose `this` for the clicked Button
With the .bind method, you could bind more than one objects (i didn't know that).

**Final code:**

```js
// listener
    let myButton = document.getElementsByClassName('myButton');
    for (var i = 0; i < myButton.length; ++i) {
      let customVar; // this gets bind with value i
      myButton[i].addEventListener("click", (function () {
        let value = myButton[numbr].getAttribute("data-value");
        this. functionToCall(value);
     }).bind(this,customVar = i));
```